# when drawing by openCV, cursor freezes over the output picture

Tags: python, opencv

when i draw an image by cv2, python3, the output is right, but the cursor keeps waiting when it passes the output picture, it's back to normal when not over the picture.

and the python icon is blank in the bottom of desk.

Why this happens and how do i fix it?

[image: error image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)
img=cv.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
cv.imshow('images',img)
cv.waitKey(1)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: you are immediately destroying the window after rendering and displaying. Try waitKey(0)

Comment: changed to waitKey(0),cursor is fine but the python icon still broken, and can't force quit  the picture doesn't have a 'close' window @Micka

Comment: maybe i shouldn't do this on jupyter notebook, i just tried IPython, it works totally fine.

Comment: Works fine form me. Maybe there is some issue with the installation? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348972/cv2-imshow-crashes-on-mac